# IntelliJ -Modules, Libraries

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package

I am a hobby programmer starting to learn Java (8) using Intellij 14.

I've written a database type program which I will continue to develop, consisting of several classes (.java) files with the same package name.

I'm a bit confused about Modules, packages and Libraries. The IntelliJ documentation seems to assume that people know what these are and how they are used.

What I want to do is to use Project A to maintain, develop and test these database classes/package and have them automatically available in other projects by using "import ;" in other projects. The other projects will then use the latest version of these files.

What is the best way to facilitate this ?

Steve

Comment: First read up on what a Java jar is, and then look into Maven or Gradle.

Comment: I would learn `maven` and define a `pom.xml` for project A and then project B. The project B would have a `<dependency>` on the latest version you built of project A. Or there are other build and dependency management tools such as `gradle`.